# Questions on while loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Hi I am new to Python and I got this question here.

Write a while loop to display the values of the Rating of an album playlist stored in the list PlayListRatings. If the score is less than 6, exit the loop. The list PlayListRatings is given by: PlayListRatings = [10, 9.5, 10, 8, 7.5, 5, 10, 10]

---

My answer is this:

```
PlayListRatings = [10,9.5,10,8,7.5,5,10,10]

i = 0

while PlayListRating[i] >= 6:

    i = i + 1

print(PlayListRatings)
```

---

The suggested answer is this:

```
PlayListRatings = [10, 9.5, 10, 8, 7.5, 5, 10, 10]

i = 1

Rating = PlayListRatings[0]

while Rating >= 6:

    print(Rating)

    Rating = PlayListRatings[i]

    i = i + 1
```

There are a few things that leave me confused:

1. Why is i=1 but not i=0 in this case? I thought i refers to the index of 10 and therefore should be i=0?
2. Why do I have to create a new variable namely Rating?
3. Why do I have to add the second to last line of the suggested answer i.e. Rating = PlayListRatings[i]?
   I couldn't execute the code without that line

Answer (score 1):

1. Since you're already taking the first element of the array (at index 0) outside the loop using:

   `Rating = PlayListRatings[0]`

So the loop will continue from the second index (i = 1)

2. The variable Rating is only a pointer to the elements of the array. You don't have to use it, you can replace it directly by `PlayListRatings[i]`
3. Since the condition of the while loop depends on the value of `Rating`, if you don't update the value of `Rating`, the condition inside the while() will stay the same each iteration, and in this case since `Rating` is taking a value of 10 the first time (since 10 is the first element of the array), this will lead to an infinite loop if the value of `Rating` is not updated, which is happening by `Rating = PlayListRatings[i]`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
PlayListRatings = [10, 9.5, 10, 8, 7.5, 5, 10, 10]
i = 0
N = len(PlayListRatings)
Rating = PlayListRatings[0]
while(i < N and Rating > 6):
     Rating = PlayListRatings[i]
     i = i + 1
     print(Rating)
```